# ControlTipText do not appear All Elements of a Userform like Textbox

Tags: excel, vba

Set property ControlTipText in Userform Textbox does not show the appropriate behavior (it does not change anything). Set manually, or for example via VBA to

```
UserForm1.Textbox1.ControlTipText= "Text"
```

I did a lot of investigation why it could happen, that after 
initializing with `Userform.show`, there is nothing appearing when moving the cursor over the TextBox as it is shown even in Videos.

The problem is probably extremely simple cause it does not depend which Userform nor which element I choose.

Comment: Can you show a bit more of the code please? `Me.TextBox1.ControlTipText = "text"` should be working.  Are the controls enabled when trying this?

Comment: There are only this 2 lines but I have to redefine the Problem .
I am Working on multiple Screens.

Comment: Are the controls enabled? `Userform.show` and `Userform1.textbox` what is the right name?

Comment: userform1
The Problem seems to be when working on multiple screens

Comment: The ControlTipText is shown on Screen1 the Userform1 on screen3